# Looking for a JS plugin or jQuery function that wait till user pauses typing in a textfield and then do a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

Some time ago I run into a function, it might have been a JS plugin, where when a user stopped typing (in a text field) for a certain amount of time, it would then perform something.

The problem is, it was a long time ago, and I haven't used it since. Now I can't remember what it was. It would be a great help if anyone knows what I am referring to.

Sorry for no code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could be thinking of the `debounce` function, which will execute a callback only after a certain amount of time has passed.

[Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) has a popular implementation, with a decent example:

```
var lazyLayout = _.debounce(calculateLayout, 300);
$(window).resize(lazyLayout);
```

Here's [a quick jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ELRYA/) demoing it.